# How to add space around removed tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="thisText">
Poem <a href="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/edgar_allan_poe/poems/18848">The Raven</a>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary... </div>

<div class="thisText">
In the greenest of our valleys By good angels tenanted..., part of<a href="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/edgar_allan_poe/poems/18848">The Haunted Palace</a>
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
all_poems = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "thisText"})
for poems in all_poems:
print(poems.text)
```

I have this sample code and i cant find how to add spaces around the removed tags so when the text inside the `<a href...>` get formatted it can be readable and wont display like this:

> PoemThe RavenOnce upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary...
>
> In the greenest of our valleys By good angels tenanted..., part ofThe Haunted Palace

Comment: Uh, your original HTML contains link text that's clumped together with adjacent words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to find all text nodes and join them with a space:

```
" ".join(item.strip() for item in poems.find_all(text=True))
```

---

Additionally, you are using `beautifulsoup3` package which is *outdated and not maintained*. Upgrade to [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and replace:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: upgrade to BS4, better - simplier and faster.

Comment: bs4 alone did not solve this for me, I had to add the `separator` parameter like the answer below recommended.

Answer (score 25):

`get_text()` in `beautifoulsoup4` has an optional input called `separator`. You can use it as follows :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.get_text(separator=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative with [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) and its `xpath` function to search for all text nodes:

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''<div class="thisText">
Poem <a href="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/edgar_allan_poe/poems/18848">The Raven</a>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary... </div>

<div class="thisText">
In the greenest of our valleys By good angels tenanted..., part of<a href="http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/edgar_allan_poe/poems/18848">The Haunted Palace</a>
</div>'''

root = etree.fromstring(html, etree.HTMLParser())
print(' '.join(root.xpath("//text()")))
```

It yields:

```
Poem  The Raven Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary...  


In the greenest of our valleys By good angels tenanted..., part of The Haunted Palace
```